# MS Graph - Client Credential Flow

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

Anyone knows using (confidential client credential flow)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow] to get the access token for an application (I am using a Java Client App using MSAL4J) if there is a way to modify the accessToken lifetime (default to 1 hour)
I tried to check the https://portal.azure.com but I did not find a clear way to do that.
I check this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes
Thanks

Comment: Pls try to follow this document to create the token lifetime policy with powershell. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-for-web-sign-in

Comment: @TinyWang Are you sure that it applies for an application using confidential client credentials flows? Also do you know if is possible doing it on UI using https://portal.azure.com/ on Azure Active Directory?

Comment: Per my test previously, it should work for any flow, and azure portal didn't have such feature till now.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t want to be rude, but what is the reason you want a longer token lifetime?

With client credentials flow, you got credentials, you exchange them for a token. That is valid for 1 hour (actually 65 minutes I believe, but that just a minor detail).

If the lifetime expired you request a new token with the same credentials.

It’s a security measure. If you leak the token the attacker has access to the resource for the rest of the lifetime of the token. That is why they keeping it long enough for an application to function, but short enough to keep the risk small.